# SQL for multiple count(*) which includes a "zero-record" information as well

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I need to run a query which find a count of different categories. For example: 
Let's say, route No: 10,20,40 are categorized under "Short-routes" and route No: "45,60 and 70" are categorized under "Long-routes". Different buses ply over one or more of these routes.

**Example:** (A, B, C are bus Nos)

Bus No.          Route

- A                 10
- A                 45
- B                 40
- B                 45
- B                 60
- A                 20
- C                 70

I am trying to write a sql query which would return the count of categories **each** bus ply **or** does not ply to (indicated by a count of zero for that category):
That is:

- Bus NO.         Short Route          Long Route
- A                 2                     1
- B                 1                     2
- C                 0                     1

The information that C does not ply (0 count) on a short route is imperative. How can I get my query to return me the result as above?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use case statements:

```
SELECT BusNo, 
    SUM (CASE WHEN Route in (10,20,40) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS ShortRoute,
    SUM (CASE WHEN Route in (45,60,70) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS LongRoute
FROM RoutesTable
GROUP BY BusNo
```

If the long/short route info is contained in another table, let's say `RouteInfo`:

```
SELECT BusNo, 
    SUM (CASE WHEN RouteInfo.Route = 'short' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS ShortRoute,
    SUM (CASE WHEN RouteInfo.Route = 'long' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS LongRoute
FROM RoutesTable
    INNER JOIN RouteInfo ON RoutesTable.Route = RouteInfo.Route
GROUP BY BusNo
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should get you on the right track.  it isn't tested especially without more specifics of you database, but you need to group by the bus numbers then you need to group by if it is a short route or not.

```
select BusNo, count(*) FROM Routes GROUP BY BusNo, isShortRoute
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` to assign whether the field matches a criteria. In this case, we'll check whether the short route is less than or equal to 40, or if the long route is greater than or equal to 45. If it is true, it will get assigned a `1`. We then take the `SUM` of both short and long routes and you get your desired result.

```
SELECT bus_no AS 'Bus No',
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN route <= 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Short Route',
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN route >= 45 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Long Route'
FROM bus GROUP BY bus_no
```